# How can I create a new page after $limit > 100?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I want to generate a new page after 100 rows or maybe even 50. When I increase `$limit` all the rows appear on a single page. Please help.

```
function new_uploaded_photos_bit2(){
$baseurl = _BASEURL_."/";
$limit ="100";  //Limit rows of 
$picnum='';
$userzoid='';
$id='';
global $relative_path;

$query="SELECT s1.fk_user_id,FROM_UNIXTIME(s1.created_on) FROM user_album2 s1
 LEFT JOIN user_album2 s2 ON s1.fk_user_id = s2.fk_user_id AND       FROM_UNIXTIME(s1.created_on) < FROM_UNIXTIME(s2.created_on)
WHERE s2.fk_user_id IS NULL ORDER by FROM_UNIXTIME(s1.created_on) DESC LIMIT $limit";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$i = 1;
$myreturn="<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" >";

while(($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) !== false) {

$profileimage = get_photo($row[0],2);
$latestphotos = member_latest_photos($row[0],12);
$name = get_name($row[0]);
$profile=get_profile_link($row[0]);
$profiletype = get_profession2($row[0]);
$i++;

$myreturn.="<tr class=\"e".($i & 1)."\" valign=\"top\">";
$myreturn.="<td width=\"80\" align=\"left\" >
<a href=\"$baseurl$profile\">
<img src=\"${relative_path}memberpictures/thumbs/$profileimage\" height=\"0\"           height=\"0\" border=\"0\"></a>
</td>";
$myreturn.="<td valign=\"top\" align=\"left\" width=\"100%\">
<strong>$name </strong> / <font color=\"#444444\">$profiletype</font>
<br>
$latestphotos
</td> ";

$myreturn.="</tr>\n";
}
$myreturn.="</table>";
return $myreturn;
}
```

Comment: Do some research on how `LIMIT` works, it can accept both the number of results to return and the starting offset. `SELECT * FROM tbl LIMIT 5,10;  # Retrieve rows 6-15`

Comment: google pagination with php mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into 'pagination' as this is what you are trying to achieve.

A common way with MySQL would be to modify the query to *limit* the number of results and also use an *offset*

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
LIMIT [number of results to return] 
OFFSET [the record to start at]
```

So if you would like 50 results on 'page 1'

```
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0 // 50 results starting at record 0
```

And then on 'page 2'

```
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 50 // 50 results starting at record 50
```

You can also use the shorthand expression (which is probably more common)

```
LIMIT [offset], [number of results]
```